# How can I obfuscate a string passed to an Attribute of a class?

Tags: string, attributes, obfuscation

I work on a plugin dll for a product.

The class of this dll requires an attribute called FeatureID which again requires a string for licensing purposes.

When I obfuscate the dll I can always see the pure string (=license code) with appropriate tools like dnSpy etc.

It seems to be not possible to define a string withon the MYNS and outside of the classe like #define ID = "XYZ", obfuscate that string and use it like [FeatuteId(ID)].

What can I do to obfuscate this license string, see code stub below:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
 public class FeatureIdAttribute : Utils.Common.Attributes.FeatureIdAttribute
 {
     public FeatureIdAttribute(string id);
 }


using xyz;

namespace MyNS
{
    [FeatureId("0TQbtG30bMrtj8")]
    [DisplayName("...")]
    [Category("...")]
    [Description("...")]
    [HelpLink("xxx")]
    public class Test : Base
    {
    }
}
```